# 2001 Suzuki Intruder W/'03 ENG burning out voltage regulator

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki

Bike will start and run for about fifteen minutes then unexpectedly quits.  Replaced voltage regulator once already.  I've checked fuses and looked for exposed wires....still no luck. Any explanations?

Comment: Is your battery ok? a bad battery can cause a regrec to fail...

Comment: How did you decide that the voltage regulator is faulty?

Comment: Are talking about the rectifier?  Are there any symptoms that occur before the bike stalls?  Does it do this when idling?  Are you driving down the road in a particular gear?  Does the bike respond erratically prior to the stall?  Please add in additional information that can assist someone in helping you.  Help us be successful.  Welcome to the site.  Thanks for the question, Please give as much data as you can.  There are a plethora of issues that can cause a stall.  Cheers!